# Flatsome UX builder is not loading the page in backend.

Tags: wordpress, wpml

I am using the WPML plugin with the flatsome theme. I have set the Italian default language for the site. And second language is English.

I have build all the pages using Ux builder in flatsome theme. When i am opening the english pages in Ux builder it is working fine for English.

The issue with the Italian language. When I am opening the Italian's language pages in UX builder it is showing loader. Not loading the builder option.

But i need to load those options because my site is already build in the UX builder. And i need to update the things in all pages.

I have updated the theme in latest version also.

In the plugin page, WPML plugins are showing notice like " To download updates or get help for this plugin, you must have a valid subscription. Buy a subscription or enter an existing key for the site ." What does it mean? Do i need to update all these plugins?

Please suggest something as it is very important to make the UX builder working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had the same problem as we used PHP 5.6 (ea-php56) on our server!!
Use PHP 7.0 (or higher) on your server and it solves the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

On my site, i had to change some server Information due to PHP.

Old:

PHP 8.020
Run Php as **FPM Application** served by Apache

to

New:

PHP 8.020
Run Php as **FastCGI Application** served by Apache